# Fetching Text just before the selected Span tag using XSLT

Tags: php, xslt, xpath

I have code that fetches a HTML code from external URL. The snipped of the code fetched is given below.

```
$output = '<div align="center" class="style12">
Monday-Thursday 3-6 March<br/>
<span class="style21">Band XYZ</span><br/>
Friday 7 March<br/>
<span class="style21">Band PQR</span><br/>
Saturday 8 March<br/>
<span class="style21">Band ABC</span><br/>
Monday-Thursday 10-13 March<br/>
<span class="style21">Band UVW</span><br/>
Friday-Saturday 14-15 March<br/>
<span class="style21">Band MNO</span>
</div>
';
```

I m trying to fetch Dates and band name from the above string, for this I m using XSLT and PHPDOM. Here is the XSLT code I have so far.

```
<xsl:for-each select="div/span">
        <xsl:variable name="band_name" select="." />
        <xsl:variable name="positions" select="position()+(position()-1)" />                                
        <xsl:variable name="raw_event_date" select="parent::div/text()[$positions]" /> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

This works well when the html are well formed, hence this code only fetches few event dates. I want to retrieve all the dates so that I want to do other way, like fetching text just before the selected span tag (excluding BRs). Can anyone throw some light on it??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="div/span">
            <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::text()[1]"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it produces:

```
Monday-Thursday 3-6 March
Friday 7 March
Saturday 8 March
Monday-Thursday 10-13 March
Friday-Saturday 14-15 March
```